# How do I edit tag's wiki?

Tags: support, tag-wiki

I have just created a tag, but I don't see a way to edit its wiki.

I have just over 2000 reputation. Is this feature unavailable to me?

Comment: I see [you just did](http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/676399)

Comment: Anyway, tag wiki edit is the same as ordinary suggested edit, it's explained in the faq.